# Postgres db constantly flooded with connections, mysterious roles -- hacked?

Tags: postgresql, security, heroku

I wrote a simple finance tracking application in 2017 that uses a Heroku backend with a Postgres db. The application suddenly stopped working, and I traced the problem to the database.

I was unable to connect to the database, seeing this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  too many connections for role
```

I thought maybe the app had a connection leak so I shut the frontend down (Im the only one that uses it) and reset all the db connections. I was then able to login to the db, and noticed all these strange roles (hundreds?) that I dont recognize.

[image: strange roles]

When I logged out of psql, I tried logging back in and again was denied with the "too many connections" error. The only way I can log back in is if I kill all connections again and immediately login. If I wait 2-3 minutes the error comes back. I don't think my heroku app is establishing all these connections with the db, because Im tailing the logs and it's just sitting there.

Does anyone have any theories about what might be going on here? Have I been hacked maybe? How would you debug this further, and how might I fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to pg_hba.conf, to make connections more restricted?

Comment: "noticed all these strange roles (hundreds?) that I don't recognize"  Isn't that just how Heroku works?  Those are the roles for other users you are sharing the hardware with.

Comment: You want to look at the connections, not the roles.  Log in, then periodically look at pg_stat_activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database has obviously been hacked.

Shut it down and delete it right away.

Restore to a different cluster from a known good backup.

From now on, choose good passwords and use a restrictive `pg_hba.conf` that for example doesn't allow remote access for superusers.

Never, ever, operate your application with a superuser.

Examine your application for SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

this may be because of a bot(made by hackers) that is scanning the internet and trying CVE exploit (N-day exploit) to see if it is vulnerable, and then launching that type of attack or it may be because someone on the VNAT with you trying to something weird, but one thing for sure it is a bot because you can not launch that many connections by hand.